# Azure: DocumentDB Mongo $group is not supported

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

After migrating my Mongo app to DocumentDB on Azure the `$group` queries are no longer working and are throwing the following error:

```
{ MongoError: '$group' is not supported',
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: '\'$group\' is not supported',
  _t: 'OKMongoResponse',
  ok: 0,
  code: 115,
  errmsg: '\'$group\' is not supported',
  '$err': '\'$group\' is not supported' }
```

Has anyone else encountered this before and may have any suggestions?

Comment: MongoDB interface for DocumentDB doesn't implement 100% of the MongoDB features (though the team has been actively adding features and publishing related blogs about updates). Seems like you've run into one of the not-yet-implemented operations (and I'm unaware of a page documenting what is and isn't implemented) . But... this isn't the place to start a discussion about how people feel about various feature gaps.

Comment: Thanks David! I wasn't sure if this was a limitation of DocumentDB or not. I've updated the question appropriately.

Comment: Why are yo migrating to DocumentDB? IMHO you'll suffer a lot migrating to DocumentDB.

Comment: @thepirat000 - This is not the place to pitch your opinion of a given product or service. You don't know a thing about the OP's product or reasons behind the migration.

Comment: @DavidMakogon No I don't know the reasons, that's why I'm asking. Just curiosity.

Comment: DocumentDB seems to have its limitations due to which I'm no longer pursuing that route. The original reason to use it was to avoid maintaining a MongoDB cluster and/or replicas with backups that guarantee a 99.9% availability. For the price point, DocumentDB offers a lot and I'll definitely consider it once it's a little more baked.

Comment: is there any link about the supported/unsupported features ?

Comment: The best link I came across is their [forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/filters/top). Hope it helps.

Comment: Still waiting for it...

Comment: DocumentDB/CosmosDB is a lie! They don't support A LOT of things (map/reduce, aggregate with group, etc.). MongoDump also fails after some documents (60Gb in my case).

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can try

(i) You could try to follow [**`documentdb-lumenize`**](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-lumenize) wrote by Larry Maccherone to provide Aggregations **`(Group-by, Pivot-table, and N-dimensional Cube)`** and Time Series Transformations as Stored Procedures in DocumentDB

(ii)Recently this feature is supproted by cosmosdb , you can enable this by Preview features pane and turn on MongoDB aggregation pipleline. Follow the following link,

[`Aggregation in cosmos-db`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-cosmosdb-extends-support-for-mongodb-aggregation-pipeline-unique-indexes-and-more/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to solve this problem in 2018+, this feature is now supported by DocumentDB, but is turned off by default. You must go into the 'Preview Features' pane in Azure and turn on 'MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline' to have access to $group.

For anyone interested in learning more, their announcement is below.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-cosmosdb-extends-support-for-mongodb-aggregation-pipeline-unique-indexes-and-more/